# create rss feeds page after posting a form in php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, forms, post, rss

my question is the following

How can I display a standard rss page after posting a form

The problem I am having, is that it is not recognized as a feed if I use the forms action
to get to the function that should echo out the rss/xml.

If I use a direct link that is pointing to the function like controller/function I am getting the expected result.

The problem with that, is that it cannot send with, the information for the rss.

Is there something I can do, to get around this?
Send the form and still get the formatted rss page(in firebug I can see it's from chrome)

Thanks, Richard

**EDIT**

```
public function rss()
    {   

        $rss = new rss('WEBTSA', 'http://taxi-bel.nl', 'WEBTSA Blogs En Meer');
        $item = array(
    'title'=>'Test Blog Post 1 Voorbeeld Site', 
    'link'=>'http://www.taxi-bel.nl/blog/rol/1/', 
    'description'=>'This example site hopes to introduce the newcomers to Zend Framework in a friendly way, by providing a simple modular site layout and can have the newcomer up and running in minutes.', 
    'pubDate'=>date(DATE_RSS),
    'image'=>array('link'=>'http://www.taxi-bel.nl', 'url'=>'http://taxi-bel.nl/images/logo_tsa_50.png', 'title'=>'WEBTSA'),
    'language'=>'en');
            /*** een nieuwe RSS instantie, geef waarden door aan de constructor ***/
            $rss = new rss('WEBTSA', 'http://taxi-bel.nl', 'WEBTSA Blogs En Meer');

            /*** voeg bovenstaande items toe ***/
            $rss->addItem($item);

            /*** toon de RSS Feed ***/
            echo $rss;
        return;
}
```

Comment: I think I have to make a link, I see that they did that here also
I thought I could avoid another db call, unless someone has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is that You should set the header Content-type to appliaction/rss+xml.

```
header('Content-type: appliaction/rss+xml');
```

just before you "echo" out the content.

Also, header must be set before You start any output on this request, else it will cause error.

Reference: http://www.rssboard.org/rss-mime-type-application.txt

Comment: thanks, I try'd that also
I get the xml output, but it is not the standard rss page, just xml